# Problem in installing g++ in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, gcc

I have a virtual machine running **Ubuntu 10.04 in VMware**.

I **gcc** version **4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)**

Upto now, we were developing only C applications. However, we will be developing C++ applications now on. So, I want to **install g++**.

When I use the **Synaptic Package Manager**, and enter **g++ in the "Quick search"** box, a list of **packages** which are **installed and NOT installed** comes up. Assuming that all the packages will be needed, I select all the packages and **click on "Apply".**

I get the following error messages:-

//==========================================================================
E: Unable to correct missing packages

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.4/g++-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5_i386.deb
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
**and similar errors for other .debs**

//==========================================================================

I **suppose this is because Ubuntu 10.04 is no longer supported**, so these packages are no longer available in the indicated repository.

So, I tried to uncheck the packages listed, and I got **"Mark additional required changes"** list. From there I have **manually noted down the list of additional packages that are required** ( Assuming that these are the dependencies for installing g++ on my system).

After that I individually **downloaded the indicated packages (the .deb files) from www.launchpad.net** and tried to **run them in a random order.**

Following are the packages I have downloaded ( list obtained by doing an 'ls' of the directory)
binutils_2.18.1~cvs20080103-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
binutils_2.19.1-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
binutils_2.20.1-3ubuntu7.3_i386.deb
binutils_2.20.51.20100908-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
cpp-4.1_4.1.2-21ubuntu1_i386.deb
cpp-4.1_4.1.2-29ubuntu1_i386.deb
cpp-4.3_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb
cpp-4.3_4.3.4-10ubuntu1_i386.deb
cpp-4.3_4.3.5-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
cpp-4.3-mips-linux-gnu_4.3.5-4_i386.deb
cpp_4.4.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
cpp-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
cpp_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
cpp_4.7.2-1_i386.deb
debconf_1.5.28ubuntu4_all.deb
findutils_4.4.0-2ubuntu4_i386.deb
findutils_4.4.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
g++-4.1_4.1.2-21ubuntu1_i386.deb
g++-4.1_4.1.2-27ubuntu1_i386.deb
g++-4.1-multilib_4.1.2-27ubuntu1lucid1_i386.deb
g++-4.3_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb
g++-4.3_4.3.4-10ubuntu1_i386.deb
g++-4.3-multilib_4.3.4-10ubuntu1_i386.deb
g++-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
g++-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5_i386.deb
g++-4.4-multilib_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
gcc-4.1_4.1.2-21ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.1_4.1.2-27ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.1-base_4.1.2-21ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.1-base_4.1.2-27ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.1-base_4.1.2-29ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.1-multilib_4.1.2-21ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.2-base_4.2.4-1ubuntu4_i386.deb
gcc-4.3_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb
gcc-4.3_4.3.4-10ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.3-base_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb
gcc-4.3-base_4.3.4-10ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.3-base_4.3.5-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.3-locales_4.3.4-10ubuntu1_all.deb
gcc-4.3-multilib_4.3.5-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc_4.4.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
gcc-4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
gcc-4.4-base_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
gcc-4.4-multilib_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
gcc-4.5-base_4.5.1-7ubuntu2_i386.deb
gcc_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
gcc-4.6_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
gcc-4.6-base_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
gcc-4.6-multilib_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
gcc-6-base_6.3.0-12ubuntu2_i386.deb
gcc-multilib_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
g++-multilib_4.4.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
hardening-wrapper_1.25_i386.deb
lib64gcc1_4.2.4-1ubuntu4_i386.deb
lib64gcc1_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
lib64gcc1_4.5.1-7ubuntu2_i386.deb
lib64gcc1_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
lib64gcc1_6.3.0-12ubuntu2_i386.deb
lib64gomp1_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
lib64gomp1_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
lib64quadmath0_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
lib64stdc++6-4.1-dbg_4.1.2-17ubuntu1_i386.deb
lib64stdc++6_4.2.4-1ubuntu4_i386.deb
lib64stdc++6_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
libc6_2.10.1-0ubuntu19_i386.deb
libc6_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21_i386.deb
libc6_2.24-9ubuntu2.2_i386.deb
libc6_2.7-10ubuntu8.3_i386.deb
libc6_2.9-4ubuntu6.3_i386.deb
libc6-amd64_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21_i386.deb
libc6-amd64_2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4_i386.deb
libc6-amd64_2.15-0ubuntu10.18_i386.deb
libc6-amd64_2.24-9ubuntu2.2_i386.deb
libc6-dev_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21_i386.deb
libc6-dev_2.7-10ubuntu8.3_i386.deb
libc6-dev-amd64_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21_i386.deb
libc6-dev-amd64_2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4_i386.deb
libc6-dev-amd64_2.15-0ubuntu10.18_i386.deb
libc-bin_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21_i386.deb
libc-dev-bin_2.11.1-0ubuntu7.21_i386.deb
libgcc1_4.2.4-1ubuntu4_i386.deb
libgcc1_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb
libgcc1_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
libgcc1_4.5.1-7ubuntu2_i386.deb
libgcc1_6.3.0-12ubuntu2_i386.deb
libgmp10_5.0.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
libgmp3c2_4.2.4+dfsg-2ubuntu1_i386.deb
libgomp1_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb
libgomp1_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
libgomp1_4.5.1-7ubuntu2_i386.deb
libmpc2_0.9-4_i386.deb
libmpfr1ldbl_2.4.0-1ubuntu3.1_i386.deb
libmpfr4_3.1.0-3ubuntu2_i386.deb
libquadmath0_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_i386.deb
libstdc++6-4.1-dbg_4.1.2-27ubuntu1_i386.deb
libstdc++6-4.1-dev_4.1.2-21ubuntu1_i386.deb
libstdc++6-4.1-dev_4.1.2-27ubuntu1_i386.deb
libstdc++6_4.2.4-1ubuntu4_i386.deb
libstdc++6-4.3-dev_4.3.3-5ubuntu4_i386.deb
libstdc++6-4.3-dev_4.3.4-10ubuntu1_i386.deb
libstdc++6-4.4-dev_4.4.3-4ubuntu5_i386.deb
mlocate_0.21.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
Packages
pentium-builder_0.19_all.deb
tzdata_2015d-0ubuntu0.10.04_all.deb
zlib1g_1.2.3.3.dfsg-12ubuntu2_i386.deb
zlib1g_1.2.3.3.dfsg-15ubuntu1_i386.deb
zlib1g_1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4_i386.deb

**Some of them installed; some of them gave me the "Dependencies NOT satisfied" message.**

**Also, now I am getting "Broken dependencies" error and "Conflicts with installed packages" message.**

I have the following questions:-

1. Is there  ***a "particular order"*** in which I need ***to install the packages*** ? [Can anyone explain in detail ***what is happening*** and ***where I am going wrong***? What are ***the basics I need to know*** ? ]
2. How do I ***fix the "Broken dependencies" error*** ?
3. How do I ***resolve the issue of "Conflicts with installed packages"*** ?
4. How do I ***get a working g++ without having to install latest version of Ubuntu*** (as **I CAN NOT CHANGE the current installation of Ubuntu 10.04**?

I have tried my best to explain my issue.

It would be really helpful if some one can answer my questions.

Thanks & Regards,
hitcha

Answer (score 1):

This problem occures because you are using and old,currently unsupported ubuntu release

The solution is simple:

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Now replace `in.archive.ubuntu.com` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

run `sudo apt update`

now you can install these packages

Comment: Running sudo apt update gives the following :-

Comment: What you got after apt update?

Comment: Running sudo apt update gives the following :-

root@developer:/etc/apt# sudo apt update

apt: invalid flag: update
Usage: apt <apt and javac options> <source files>
...................................
warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  .......and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.

root@developer:/etc/apt#

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Doesnot work. 
root@developer:~/Software/all# sudo apt-get update
apt-get: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by apt-get)
apt-get: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6.so.4.8)

Comment: How do I proceed ?

Comment: Thank you for providing the lead.I was finally able to install g++ on Ubuntu 10.04 WITHOUT having to upgrade to a higher distro of Ubuntu.